# Makefile builds target every time

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I have written a makefile to compile all the sources in different directories and build a target. When I run make even when there is no change in the files, it does not re-compiles the unmodified files. But, it always builds the target. Why is the target alone getting built every time when I run make?

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = $(INCLUDES)
TARGET = FinalBin
OUTDIR := obj

INCLUDES = -Isrc/in
S1 = src/s1
S2 = src/s2

S1_SRC = $(wildcard $(S1)/*.c)
S2_SRC = $(wildcard $(S2)/*.c)
SRCS := $(S1_SRC) \
    $(S2_SRC)

OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,$(OUTDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))

SRCDIRS := $(S1) $(S2)

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): builddir $(OBJS)
    @echo "Building..." $@
    @$(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@
    @echo "Build Complete!"

$(OUTDIR)/%.o: %.c
    @echo "Compiling.." $(notdir $<)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -c $< -o $@

clean:
    -@rm -rf $(OUTDIR) FinalBin
    @echo "Clean complete!"

builddir :
    @$(call create-dir)

define create-dir
    for dir in $(SRCDIRS); \
    do \
        mkdir -p $(OUTDIR)/$$dir; \
    done
endef

-include $(wildcard $(OBJS:.o=.d))
```

The $(TARGET) gets built from the object files each time. Please guide me where I'm going wrong.

**UPDATE:**

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = $(INCLUDES)
TARGET = FinalBin
OUTDIR := obj

INCLUDES = -Isrc/in
S1 = src/s1
S2 = src/s2

S1_SRC = $(wildcard $(S1)/*.c)
S2_SRC = $(wildcard $(S2)/*.c)
SRCS := $(S1_SRC) \
    $(S2_SRC)

OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,$(OUTDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))

SRCDIRS := $(S1) $(S2)
OUTDIRS := $(addprefix $(OUTDIR)/,$(SRCDIRS))

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    @echo "Building..." $@
    @$(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@
    @echo "Build Complete!"

$(OUTDIR)/%.o: $(OUTDIRS) %.c
    @echo "Compiling.." $(notdir $(filter %.c,$^))
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -c $(filter %.c,$^) -o $@

clean:
    -@rm -rf $(OUTDIR) FinalBin
    @echo "Clean complete!"

$(OUTDIRS):
    mkdir -p $@

builddir :
    @$(call create-dir)

define create-dir
    for dir in $(SRCDIRS); \
    do \
        mkdir -p $(OUTDIR)/$$dir; \
    done
endef

-include $(wildcard $(OBJS:.o=.d))
```

This builds all the files every time.

**Final Solution:**

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = $(INCLUDES)
TARGET = FinalBin
OUTDIR := obj

INCLUDES = -Isrc/in
S1 = src/s1
S2 = src/s2

S1_SRC = $(wildcard $(S1)/*.c)
S2_SRC = $(wildcard $(S2)/*.c)
SRCS := $(S1_SRC) \
    $(S2_SRC)

OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,$(OUTDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))

SRCDIRS := $(S1) $(S2)
OUTDIRS := $(addprefix $(OUTDIR)/,$(SRCDIRS))

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OUTDIRS) $(OBJS)
    @echo "Building..." $@
    @$(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@
    @echo "Build Complete!"

$(OUTDIR)/%.o: %.c
    @echo "Compiling.." $(notdir $<)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -c $< -o $@

clean:
    -@rm -rf $(OUTDIR) FinalBin
    @echo "Clean complete!"

$(OUTDIRS):
    @mkdir -p $@

-include $(wildcard $(OBJS:.o=.d))
```

The final solution works as expected!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the debug output of make to look for what it thinks needs rebuilding:

```
make -d | grep remake
```

You'll probably see something like this:

```
No need to remake target `Makefile'.
    Must remake target `builddir'.
      No need to remake target `src/s1/x.c'.
    No need to remake target `obj/src/s1/x.o'.
  Must remake target `FinalBin'.
Must remake target `all'.
```

Which shows that it always thinks that the `builddir` target needs to be remade. Since that is a dependency of `$(TARGET)` it rebuilds the latter as well.

If you use a rule to create your build directories instead of a function, `make` will know whether it needs create them or not. For example, adding the variable `$(OUTDIRS)`, a rule for it, and making this a dependency of compiling:

```
SRCDIRS := $(S1) $(S2)
OUTDIRS := $(addprefix $(OUTDIR)/, $(SRCDIRS)) # <---------- Add this variable

All: $(TARGET) 

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    @echo "Building..." $@
    @$(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@
    @echo "Build Complete!"

$(OUTDIR)/%.o: $(OUTDIRS) %.c # <--------------------------- Add dependency to $(OUTDIRS)
    @echo "Compiling.." $(notdir $<)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -c $< -o $@

clean:
    -@rm -rf $(OUTDIR) FinalBin
    @echo "Clean complete!"

$(OUTDIRS): # <--------------------------------------------- Add rule
    mkdir -p $@

-include $(wildcard $(OBJS:.o=.d))
```

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tip! I have now made it as `all: builddir $(TARGET)`. It is not building the $(TARGET) everytime. But, is it possible to make it print that there is nothing to build?

Comment: @Gomu I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but I edited my answer with an alternative way of doing what you're going for.

Comment: I have updated the question with the suggested modification. But, now all the files are getting compiled every time. Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: My earlier question was, actually with the initial change of `all: builddir $(TARGET)`, when there is nothing to build, the make was not printing `Nothing to build` message. It was just exiting. Thats why I was asking if it was possible to manually echo that message.

Comment: If I add the `$(OUTDIRS)` as dependency to `$(TARGET)`, then it is working as expected. It even prints the `Nothing to be done for `all'.` when there is nothing to build. Thanks for your help!