# How to avoid running all targets every time a makefile is run?

Tags: makefile

How can I avoid rebuilding of targets every time even though there are no changes to them? I have looked at these answers: [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289026/makefile-always-running-target), [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740853/why-a-makefile-target-is-always-run), [answer3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483162/makefile-builds-target-every-time), but I still could not solve my problem. I think I understand conceptually why this problem occurs. It is just that I was unable to apply the solutions to my case.

Here is my makefile:

```
.PHONY: all dircreate dircreate_sub

# Create shortcuts to directories ##############################################
DAT4 = data/4-Year/
RES4 = data/results/4-Year/
FIG4 = figures/4-Year/
DAT2 = data/2-Year/
RES2 = data/results/2-Year/
FIG2 = figures/2-Year/
DEPVARS = \
    ret.1st.2nd.term.left \
    ret.1st.2nd.year.left \
    ret.1st.7th.year.grad \
    ret.1st.5th.year.grad

# Create directories ###########################################################
dircreate:
    mkdir -p \
    data/ \
    data/4-Year/ \
    data/2-Year/ \
    data/results/ \
    data/results/4-Year \
    data/results/2-Year \
    figures/ \
    figures/4-Year/ \
    figures/2-Year/

dircreate_sub:
    for d in $(DEPVARS); do \
        mkdir -p data/4-Year/$$d ; \
        mkdir -p data/2-Year/$$d ; \
        mkdir -p data/results/4-Year/$$d ; \
        mkdir -p data/results/2-Year/$$d ; \
        mkdir -p figures/4-Year/$$d ; \
        mkdir -p figures/2-Year/$$d ; \
    done;

#TARGETS_DATAPREP := \
#$(foreach dat, $(DAT4) $(DAT2), $\
#   $(foreach filename, \
#           train_index_outer.RDS \
#           train_outer.RDS \
#           train_inter_outer.RDS, $\
#               $(foreach depvar, $(DEPVARS),$(dat)$(depvar)/$(filename))))

# Data prep:####################################################################
TARGETS_DATAPREP := \
$(foreach filename, $\
    train_index_outer.RDS \
    train_outer.RDS \
    train_inter_outer.RDS \
    entire_data.RDS \
    entire_inter_data.RDS, $\
        $(foreach depvar, $(DEPVARS),$(DAT4)$(depvar)/$(filename)))

$(TARGETS_DATAPREP): \
    dataprep.R \
    funcs.R \
    ../core/data/analysis.data.RDS
    Rscript $<

# benchmark:####################################################################
DEPENDENCIES_BENCHMARK := \
$(foreach filename, $\
    train_index_outer.RDS \
    train_outer.RDS \
    train_inter_outer.RDS \
    entire_data.RDS \
  entire_inter_data.RDS, $\
        $(foreach depvar, $(DEPVARS),$(DAT4)$(depvar)/$(filename)))

TARGETS_BENCHMARK := \
$(foreach filename, $\
    logreg_inner.RDS \
    l1logreg_inner.RDS \
    l1logreg.int_inner.RDS \
    rf_inner.RDS \
    xgb_inner.RDS \
    logreg_outer.RDS \
    l1logreg_outer.RDS \
    l1logreg.int_outer.RDS \
    rf_outer.RDS \
    xgb_outer.RDS, $\
        $(foreach depvar, $(DEPVARS),$(RES4)$(depvar)/$(filename)))

$(TARGETS_BENCHMARK): \
    benchmark.R \
    funcs.R \
    $(DEPENDENCIES_BENCHMARK)
    Rscript $<

# Process:######################################################################
TARGETS_PROCESS := \
$(foreach filename, $\
    processed_inner.RDS \
    processed_inner_outer.RDS, $\
        $(foreach depvar, $(DEPVARS),$(RES4)$(depvar)/$(filename)))

$(TARGETS_PROCESS): \
    process.R \
    funcs.R \
    $(TARGETS_BENCHMARK)
    Rscript $<

# Graphs:#######################################################################
TARGETS_GRAPHS := \
$(foreach filename, $\
    ave_auc_inner.png \
    ave_ppv10_inner.png \
    dist_auc_inner.png \
    dist_ppv10_inner.png \
    roc_inner.png \
    ave_auc_outer.png \
    ave_ppv10_outer.png \
    dist_auc_outer.png \
    dist_ppv10_outer.png \
    roc_outer.png \
    ave_auc_ppv10_inner_outer.png \
    roc_inner_outer.png \
    thresh_inner_outer.png, $\
        $(foreach depvar, $(DEPVARS),$(FIG4)$(depvar)/$(filename)))

$(TARGETS_GRAPHS): \
    graphs.R \
    funcs.R \
    $(TARGETS_PROCESS)
    Rscript $<

# Make all
all: $(TARGETS_PROCESS)
```

So, the `make -nd` tells me `dircreate` needs to be remade every time. That's why I also tried adding a variable called, say, `OUTDIRS` and also created a rule for it. So, instead of `dircreate`, I added this bit:

```
OUTDIRS: $(DAT4) $(RES4) $(FIG4) $(DAT2) $(RES2) $(FIG2)
OUTDIRS := \
for d in $(DEPVARS); do \
    $(DAT4)$$d ; \
    $(DAT2)$$d ; \
    $(RES4)$$d ; \
    $(RES2)$$d ; \
    $(FIG4)$$d ; \
    $(FIG2)$$d ; \
done;

$(OUTDIRS):
  mkdir -p $@
```

But, this time I get a missing separator error at `$(OUTDIRS): mkdir -p $@`, which, I know, is unrelated to the main question, but I am wondering if the way I am going about is at least on the right track?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html

Comment: You should simplify your question -- people are unlikely to read through the entire makefile you posted.   Try recreating a minimal example that does the behavior you're after.

Comment: The reason `dircreate` needs to run every time is because there's no file named `dircreate` created by that target.  For make, if a file does not exist then it's always out of date and will try to be created.  The reason it tries to recreate `dircreate` when you run `make` is that unless you specify a particular target, make always tries to build the first target in the makefile, which here is `dircreate`.  As for the last bit "are you on the right track", I have no idea what you're trying to do here so I can't tell.

Comment: Are you trying to create a list of subdirectories for use in your static pattern rule? That is, given `DIRS := data/2-Year data 4-Year` and `DEPVARS := ret.1st.2nd.term.left ret.1st.2nd.year.left`, to construct `data/2-Year/ret.1st.2nd.term.left data/2-Year/ret.1st.2nd.year.left data/4-Year/ret.1st.2nd.term.left data/4-Year/ret.1st.2nd.year.left`?

Comment: @Beta  Yes, ```dircreate``` is meant to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have

```
DIRS := 2-Year 4-Year
DEPVARS := term year
```

and you want to construct:

```
2-Year/term 2-Year/year 4-Year/term 4-Year/year
```

You can do it this way:

```
OUTDIRS := $(foreach d,$(DIRS),$(addprefix $(d)/,$(DEPVARS)))
```

And once you have that working you can abstract it into a function:

```
Multiply= $(foreach d,$(1),$(addprefix $(d)/,$(2)))

OUTDIRS:=$(call Multiply, $(DIRS), $(DEPVARS))
```

And one you have *that* working you can use it to construct those trees of yours:

```
DIRS := data data/results figures
DIRS := $(DIRS) $(call Multiply, $(DIRS), 4-Year 2-Year)

DEPVARS := $(addprefix ret.1st., 2nd.term.left 2nd.year.left 7th.year.grad 5th.year.grad)

OUTDIRS:=$(call Multiply, $(DIRS), $(DEPVARS))

$(OUTDIRS):
    mkdir -p $@
```

Note that if you want Make to create whichever of those directories don't exist, you must add another rule *before* the `$(OUTDIRS)` rule:

```
.PHONY: all-dirs
all-dirs: $(OUTDIRS)
```